# Tarballing in Bash: Is there a way to only dereference links pointing outside the tar'd directory?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I regularly use the `-h` tag of `tar` to create tarballs that contain all the libaries linked to from the directory I am zipping up, but it has to side-effect of double-tarballing all the internal links within the directory.

For example, I have two very large datasets, and use a symbolic link to choose which one my test app uses, so I end up getting one of them twice. This makes the tarball *way* bigger than it needs to be.

So, is there any way to get `tar` to only dereference links if they point to a file that's not already included in the tarball?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead to make a list of files to be included into the `tar` ball.

```
find . -exec realpath '{}' ';' | sort | uniq | tar -T -
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The first part in the chain just returns a bunch of lines of `find: 'realpath': No such file or directory`.

Comment: `realpath` is not a very common program. It doesn't seem to be installed.